# Azure Log Stream Logs missing - Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

In my Azure Function, I am using SLF4J for logging (backed by logback). Application Insights supports auto-instrumented logging. Where the logs are automatically collected. Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config#auto-collected-logging).

But I find that randomly a lot of logs get missed. They are present during a run and missing some other times when viewed in LogStream. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not fully answer the question. I still find the issue present. And don't really know the cause for missing logs in LogStream. And it is frustrating.

---

One thing that you may want to further take care is: [Sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config#sampling). Pasting from the docs:

> Sampling is helpful if you need to reduce cost. Sampling is performed
> as a function on the operation ID (also known as trace ID), so that
> the same operation ID will always result in the same sampling
> decision. This ensures that you won't get parts of a distributed
> transaction sampled in while other parts of it are sampled out.
>
> For example, **if you set sampling to 10%, you will only see 10% of your
> transactions**, but each one of those 10% will have full end-to-end
> transaction details.

To avoid filtering due to sampling, add the function configuration:

```
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_SAMPLING_PERCENTAGE: 100
```

This does not omit anything.
For more details, visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config#sampling

---

In my case, I wanted to include all the logs. But perform sampling for other metrics (like dependencies which includes calls to REST API, database or a file system).

An alternative way as well. Edit your `host.json` as:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "excludedTypes": "Exception;Trace;Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The log statements as such go under `Trace`. So we exclude sampling for it. The rest are sampled (Dependency, Event, PageView, Request)

To validate if the above config is working as expected, run the below kusto query:

```
union requests,dependencies,pageViews,browserTimings,exceptions,traces
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| summarize RetainedPercentage = 100/avg(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), itemType
```

Load test the function. In the output, you should see 100 across the `Exception;Trace;Request`

[image]

To view full set of config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#sample-hostjson-file

To selectively override (different behavior for different logs): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config#sampling-overrides-preview

---